# Css :after property not working in IE

Tags: css

I am using css :target property but it is not working in IE8, is there any hack to make it work?

Comment: Normal IE8 or IE8 compatibility mode?

Answer (score 0):

IE8 supports `:before` and `:after` - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304082(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Perhaps it is being overridden by something else?

Comment: .box:target span{   
   height: 32px;
   width: 99px;
   background: #fff;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: -32px;
   z-index:0;
  }

Comment: :target is not supported, but support can be added with JS library + selectivizr - http://selectivizr.com/

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp a Doctype has to be declared on the page for the :after property to work. Does this help? Would also help if you posted code.

Answer (score 0):

try using this at the start of HTML file. Then it supports :before, :after property.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

**:target** property is CSS3 property. IE8 doesn't support most of CSS3 styles.

Answer (score 0):

you can use .next() or .closet() method in jquery

for example

```
$(function() {
    $('span').next().css('color','red');

    })

<span>hiiii</span>
<p>byeee</p>
```

the red color apply on p tag